# How to replace plus sign with other string python

Tags: python

```
user_input = input("INPUT: ")
# 2x-1=1+6
left = user_input.split("=")[0]
right = user_input.split("=")[1]
print(left, right)

left_term = left.replace("+",",+")
left_term = left.replace("-",",-")
right_term = right.replace("+",",+")
right_term = right.replace("-",",-")
print(left_term,right_term)

terms_x = []
```

It just shows me
2x, -1 1+6

but i want is 2x, -1 1, +6

So, main question is how to replace "+" with other string.

Comment: You're *overwriting* `left_term` again with `left.replace(...)`…!  http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code was not working was because you're storing

> right_term = right.replace("+",",+")

and again overwriting the value of *right_term* by

> right_term = right_term.replace("-",",-")

because of which the previously replaced string is not being used anymore,
hence fixing your code would look like:

```
user_input = input("INPUT: ")
# 2x-1=1+6
left = user_input.split("=")[0]
right = user_input.split("=")[1]
print(left, right)

left_term = left.replace("+",",+")
left_term = left_term.replace("-",",-")
right_term = right.replace("+",",+")
right_term = right_term.replace("-",",-")
print(left_term,right_term)

terms_x = []
```

have added this so you could know what was actually causing it to not work.

Comment: @조민석 You're welcome! Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was useful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace directly the main `string` before splitting from `=` like this:

```
user_input = input("INPUT: ")
# 2x-1=1+6
spl = user_input.replace("+",", +").replace("-",", -").split("=")
left = spl[0]
right = spl[1]
print(left, right)

terms_x = []
```

So the **output** would be:
`2x, -1 1, +6`

Comment: @조민석 You're welcome! Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was useful to you.